# Unit test ASP.NET Core WebApi. Как написать Mock для Request.Headers для коректной работы теста

Tags: юнит-тесты, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, mocking, xunit

В контроллере есть такой метод:

```
private Person AuthUser()
    {
        string personName = Request.Headers["unique_name"];
        Person person = new Person();

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(personName))
        {
            person = _personService.GetAllPersons().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Email == personName);
        }

        return person;
    }
```

Его мы используем для передачи объекта в сервис и т.д.

```
    [Route("update")]
    [HttpPut]
    public bool Update([FromBody]IEnumerable<VacancyModel> vacancyModels)
    {
        if (vacancyModels == null || vacancyModels.Count() < 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _vacancyService.UpdateVacancy(vacancyModels, AuthUser());

        return true;
    }
```

Для теста пишу следующее:

```
    [Fact]
    public void VacancyController_Update_Test()
    {
        _mockVacancyService.Setup(back => back.InsertVacancy(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Vacancy>>())).Returns(true);

        //Controller initial
         _vacancyController = VacancyControllerInit();

        var headerDictionary = new HeaderDictionary();
        headerDictionary["unique_name"] = "test@test.test";
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
        List<StringValues> coll = new List<StringValues>();
        coll.Add(headerDictionary["unique_name"]);
        request.Setup(r => r.Headers.Values).Returns(coll);

        var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
        httpContext.SetupGet(a => a.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        var cc = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        cc.Setup(b => b.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext.Object);

        _vacancyController.ControllerContext = cc.Object;

        Assert.True(_vacancyController.Insert(new List<VacancyModel> { MockedData.VacancyModelItem }));
    }
```

Пробывал разные варианты, либо тест завершается с ошибками, а в данном случае получаем Exception:

[image: Exception]

Т.к. в ASP.NET Core изменились некоторые интерфейсы и классы, работающие примеры сейчас не актуальны для моей проблемы.

UPDATE:

Данная проблема решается следующим путем:

```
public ControllerConstructorTest()
    {
        var headerDictionary = new HeaderDictionary();
        headerDictionary["some"] = "some";
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
        List<StringValues> stringValuesCollection = new List<StringValues>();
        stringValuesCollection.Add(headerDictionary["unique_name"]);
        request.Setup(r => r.Headers.Values).Returns(stringValuesCollection);

        httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
        httpContext.SetupGet(a => a.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    }
```

И дальше в самом тестовом методе выполняется инициализация HttpContext-а
через ControllerContext.

Пример:

```
    [Fact]
    public void VacancyController_Update_Test()
    {
        _mockVacancyService.Setup(back => back.UpdateVacancy(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Vacancy>>())).Returns(true);

        //Controller initial
        _vacancyController = VacancyControllerInit();

        _vacancyController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
        {
            HttpContext = httpContext.Object
        };

        Assert.True(_vacancyController.Update(new List<VacancyModel> { MockedData.VacancyModelItem }));
    }
```

Все это делается из-за того что на прямую установить HttpContext не получится
т.к. он имеет свойство - read-only, собственно в этом и была проблема.